# how can I escape from main while loop(C programming)?

Tags: c, while-loop, embedded, interrupt, rs485

I am trying to escape from the main loop if external stop key is pressed.
Currently, communicating AT32UC with ATmega128 through RS485 communication where START and STOP keys are implemented.
RS485 receiver interrupt is called if there is data to be processed in the receiver side where 0x10 = Start and 0x11 = Stop.

My problem is that start and stop keys are recognised well and main loop is continued if start and I would like to terminate the main loop if stop key is pressed. 
So I've set the start flag and stop flag accordingly. But, I am struggling with stop(escape) implementation. Below is brief snippets of interrupt routine and main loop.

```
__attribute__((__interrupt__)) static void rs485RxInterrupt(void)
{
uint32_t data;
static char RxDatalength = 98;
data = AVR32_USART2.RHR.rxchr;

    if(data & 0x00000100) // rs485 9 bit check 
    {
        if((data & 0x000000ff) == 0x92) //dsp board address = 0x92
        {
            rxBuf[0] = data;
            addr_flag = true;
            rxInCtr = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            addr_flag = false;
            return;
        }
     }

     else if (addr_flag == true) // if 9 bit is checked
     {
         rxBuf[rxInCtr++] = data;
         if(rxInCtr == 2)           // command check
         {
            if(data < 0x80)
            {   
                if(data==0x10)  // start command
                {
                    addr_flag = false;  // reset addr flag
                    start_flag = true;
                    //RxDatalength = 0;
                }
                else if(data == 0x11)    // stop command
                    break_flag = true;
            }
            else if(data >= 0x80)
                //gpio_set_pin_high (AVR32_PIN_PA16);
                RxDatalength = 3;
        }

         if ((rxInCtr == RxDatalength) || ((RxDatalength == 98) && (rxInCtr == rxBuf[2]+1)))   // end of packet recognition
         {
            addr_flag = false;
            start_flag = true;
         }
     }
}

int main()
{
......
while(!break_flag)
{

    start_flag = false;
    while(start_flag == false)
    ;

    gpio_set_pin_high(AVR32_PIN_PA14);
    delay_us(40);
    gpio_set_pin_low(AVR32_PIN_PA14);

    //****** loop stays at this point and I am not giving sync_flag high to          
    //continue so if I press stop, I want this thing to get out of the main   
    //while loop!!


    //      peaksRdy_flag = true;
    //      SendTx(peaks);

    sync_flag = false;      // synchronising main with start of the input
    while(sync_flag == false)
        ;           
    envelopeIndex = 0;  


    for(uint32_t loop=0; loop<23; loop++)   // looping 23 times to cover approx 4.5s
    {           
        //reset counter
        sampleCounter = 0;
        samplingComplete = false;       

        //wait for sampling to finish, 256 samples
        while (samplingComplete == false)
            ;

        //gpio_set_pin_low(AVR32_PIN_PA15); // main loop indicator

        windowing(x);
        rms(x); // return ac_rms

        //gpio_set_pin_low(AVR32_PIN_PA16); // fft indicator
        fft_run(window);    // return fft magnitude
        //gpio_set_pin_high(AVR32_PIN_PA16);

        peak_search(fft_mag);
        envelope_output(envelope);

        // Function to transmit analysed data through RS485 communication.  
        //SendTx(peaks);

        sprintf(filtResult, "%04d %04d %04d %04d %04d\n", (int)peaks[loop][0], (int)peaks[loop][1], (int)peaks[loop][2], (int)peaks[loop][3],(int)ac_rms);
        char *ptr = &filtResult[0];
        do
        {
            c = *ptr;
            ptr++;
            usart_bw_write_char(&AVR32_USART2, (int)c);
            // sendByte(c);

        } while (c != '\n');
        //gpio_set_pin_high(AVR32_PIN_PA15);

    } // outer loop

        sprintf(filtResult, "%04d\n", (int)duty);
        char *ptr = &filtResult[0];
        do
            {
                c = *ptr;
                ptr++;
                usart_bw_write_char(&AVR32_USART2, (int)c);
                // sendByte(c);
            } while (c != '\n');
    break;
    }//while

 }//main
```

Comment: why "while(start_flag == false)
    ; " ?.. what is the scope and what is it supposed to do?.. there isn't an open or close bracket anywhere and its not doing or calling anything to make it stop

Comment: Hi, my intention there is to wait for start flag to go high in and continue. Similar to the synchronisation part just below which it waits for synchronisation flag to go high and continue. 
And I am currently watching gpio pin14 high and low for debugging. Is it functioning differently to my intention? Sorry I am a newbie to the programming world :)

Comment: In addition, the gpio pin14 goes high if I press start and comes low if I press stop. But it does not go high again if I press start after stop key.

Comment: it think its just an issue with not using Global variables.. you set your break_flag, start_flag, and sync_flag flag locally.. try declaring them as global variables so that data updates are saved

Comment: @FrancisFuerte If the variables weren't already at file scope, he couldn't very well be accessing them from inside the ISR now could he?

Comment: Where sync_flag is set to true???

Comment: Just one question: **Where** do you want to return to from `main` actually?

Comment: Please indent the code consistently.  As it is, it is very difficult to determine to current depth of looping at any specific line of code.   Never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest: indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Answer (score 6):

All your flags should be declared volatile.

eg:

```
volatile int start_flag, sync_flag /*,other_flag ... */;
```

else the compiler may optimise out checks for their value being changed by code outside the current block.

Comment: Most likely this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks all for kind suggestions.
my flags are all declared globally as volatile int, and not quite sure why its not working yes..
so I am currently re-implementing main loop into state machine. hopefully this will solve the problem!